# Solving Partial Differential Equation with Self-similar Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, error-function

$$
Greetings,
$$
So, I have a heat equation to be solved for in the form of
$$
\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$
for t = [0,+inf) and x = (-inf,+inf)

and following I.C and B.C:
$$
f(x,0)=1,x\geq0
$$
$$
f(x,0)=0,x<0
$$
$$
f(-\inf,t)=0
$$
$$
f(+\inf,t)=1
$$
I work out the solution roughly using the following procedure:

1. $f(x,t)=f(\eta)$, with $\eta = \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$
2. Obtain ODE as
   $$
   \frac{d^2 f(\eta)}{d\eta^2}+\frac{1}{2}\eta\frac{df}{d\eta}=0
   $$
3. Solve ODE using $u=\frac{df}{d\eta}$
4. Obtain $u=C_1e^{-\frac{1}{4}\eta^2}$

and here is where I started get confusing, I went ahead and solve for $f$ using $u$ obviously and end up with an integral that looks like
$$
df = C_1e^{-\frac{1}{4}\eta^2} d\eta
$$
The question also hitted that using error function to simplify the solution
$$
erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-y^2}dy
$$
Thus, using $y=\frac{1}{2}\eta$, I can manage to get an integral that looks similar
$$
f = C_1\int e^{-y^2} dy
$$

So, my question is

1) What is the trick to convert the indefinite integral to a definite one

2) I can find the $C_2$ which is obtained after integrating the last integral as well as $C_1$ just by using the B.C. ONLY. What happens to the I.C. in this case? Does it do anything, and why?

First question post here,

Thank you all in advance

Cheers,